# Big Query SQL sum values based on conditions

Tags: sql, join, count, google-bigquery

I have a query where I am trying to combine tables and sum results based on a combination of two columns. I want to combine the group from table 2 and 3 to be matched with the name and count of table 1. Then, the count should be summed so each name is listed once. However, IF a person worked are group UU AND group Z, THEN he/she should needs to have their group Z count listed separately from their group UU count. This person would be listed twice if they worked as group Z and UU. I need to split out results based on a specific condition (the combination of Portal and Group in the example below)

```
Table 1
+--------+------+-------+
| Portal | Name | Count |
+--------+------+-------+
| A      | Bob  |     3 |
| A      | Joe  |     6 |
| B      | Joe  |     6 |
| B      | Bob  |     2 |
| C      | Bob  |     5 |
+--------+------+-------+

Table 2
+-------+------+
| Group | Name |
+-------+------+
| Z     | Bob  |
| Y     | Joe  |
+-------+------+ 

Table 3
+-------+------+
| Group | Name |
+-------+------+
| UU    | Bob  |
| UU    | Jill |
+-------+------+

Output
+-------+------+-------+
| Group | Name | Count |
+-------+------+-------+
| Z     | Bob  |     8 |
| UU    | Bob  |     2 |
| Y     | Joe  |    12 |
+-------+------+-------+
```

Notice that Bob's Portal B gets counted separately because he is in Group UU. Group UU only works in portal B. Bob's Portal A and C gets summed together because he is group Z in those Portals. Meanwhile Joe gets all of his count summed in a single row because he is not UU at all. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: How do the groups and the portals relate? Your sample data has no indication of that. On the other hand, you have to table of user groups, whose purpose seems unclear.

Comment: you should explain in more details - each and every row in output. so far - it is very unclear and confusing  to the point of making no sense at all

Comment: Please explain how you calculate `8` and `2`.  How do you know "A" and "C go with "Z"?

Comment: The only relation is that Group UU is always in Portal B. Other than that, there is no relation. Any group can work in any portal. Output: Bob is Z in every portal except portal B. By adding 5+3 (the count from portal A and C) you get 8. Bob is UU in portal B, so we get 2 from portal B. Joe is group Y, so we add up all his counts from all his portals without separating at all.A person can be group Z and group UU, but they only work in Portal B as group UU.

Comment: What I am doing is adding the group to the name, and adding all the count together for all the portals. The only exception is that when a person is Group UU role, which only occurs in Portal B, that count needs to be separate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Try below

```
#standardSQL
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 'A' portal, 'Bob' name, 3 cnt UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', 'Joe', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'Joe', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'Bob', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'Bob', 5 
), table2 AS (
  SELECT 'Z' grp, 'Bob' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Y', 'Joe' 
), table3 AS (
  SELECT 'UU' grp, 'Bob' name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'UU', 'Jill' 
), all_groups AS (
  SELECT * FROM table2 UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM table3
)
SELECT grp, name, 
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN grp = 'UU' THEN
        CASE WHEN portal = 'B' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END
      WHEN grp != 'UU' AND flag THEN
        CASE WHEN portal = 'B' THEN 0 ELSE cnt END
      ELSE cnt
    END
  ) cnt
FROM (
  SELECT a.grp, a.name, b.portal, b.cnt, 
    0 != COUNTIF(grp = 'UU') OVER(PARTITION BY a.name) flag
  FROM all_groups a
  JOIN table1 b
  ON a.name = b.name
)
GROUP BY grp, name
```

with output

```
Row grp name    cnt  
1   Z   Bob     8    
2   UU  Bob     2    
3   Y   Joe     12
```

Comment: This did the trick. It does list people like Bob twice even though they only worked in portal B (not necessarily what I want), but the count is 0 and shouldn't affect weighted averages. I can work around it. I tip my hat and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use a different mapping table depending on the value of the portal. If so, you can do:

```
select 
    case when portal = 'B' then t3.group else t2.group end as grp,
    t1.name,
    sum(count) cnt
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
inner join table3 t2 on t2.name = t1.name
group by 1, 2
```

If you may have missing records in any of the group table, then use `left join` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not separate, it lists the people with group UU and group B by group as expected, but does not separate out the count. I'm assuming labelling table 3 alias as t2 was a mistake. Your output was "Z Bob 10" followed by "UU Bob 10". Would you prefer to see the entire 84 line query? It does everything I want, except when I have a person (Bob) with Group UU and Group Z, Bob's is listed as Group UU twice, first with the count doubled, and then quadrupled. I was worried if I posted entire code I would spend a week explaining it, if anyone took the time.